# Python udp performance

Tags: python, performance, sockets

I am setting up a pretty simple message server using TCP and UDP on different ports on a Raspberry PI 2 with wifi.  I am using UDP for multi-cast.  The server works fine.  The problem is that the processor jumps to about 30% processor usage when I run the server (TCP and UDP listeners).  This isn't processing anything, just listening. When I shut down the UDP it goes to about 3-5%. Is this normal (it is a RPi), or am I doing something wrong?  Here is the code for initializing the UDP listener:

```
class UDPServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
  def __init__(self):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    multicast_group = '224.3.29.71'
    server_address = ('', 8081)

    # Create the socket
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    # Bind to the server address
    self.bind(server_address)


    group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group)
    mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
    self.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
    print("UDP listening on {}:{}".format(multicast_group,8081))
```

Comment: `server_address = ('', 8081)` it is bad idea ! try local or which hardware address available.You serve on wifi but work on  all interfaces, all networks got a delay but you scan rapidly, why ?

Comment: Unrelated: the docs say you should use `asyncio` instead of `asyncore`.

Comment: I have a version that does use a specific address, but I am actually going to use this in a set of cloud servers as well and was being lazy :). I will fix that when I actually use this, but I checked and that does not impact the performance.  As far as the scan rate, I am using the loop function of asynccore - is that what you are referring to? I will check out asyncio.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to get back to this, but J.F. Sebastian has the solution.  I implemented `asyncio` and it works with very little overhead.  I straight copied the demo from Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio-udp-echo-server-protocol). The only issue with asyncio is that it appears to be listed as provisional so technically it could be removed later.  If you want credit for an answer move your comment to an answer and I will mark it.  Thanks J. F. Sebastion and dsgdfg.